# Time-frequency analysis

Tags: time-frequency

I had this question in the exam without any further explanation.

Why the time translation invariance is an important feature for time-frequency distributions?

I am writing to ask whether anyone can please explain what is time translation invariance? And why is it important feature?

Comment: Cool, but which part don't you understand? I presume you've read about that.